# Running Apache Beam pipeline on Azure Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, apache-beam, azure-databricks

I'm doing POC with KafkaIO and spark runner on Azure Databricks. I'm trying
to create a simple streaming app with Apache Beam, where it reads data from
an Azure event hub and produces messages into another Azure event hub.

I'm creating and running spark jobs on Azure Databricks.

The problem is the consumer (uses SparkRunner) is not receiving any messages
from Event hub (topic). There is no activity and no errors on the Spark
cluster.

I tried to consume event hub messages without using Apache beam on the same cluster and it is working without any issues.

This is my simple Apache beam pipeline which consumes json message, transforms and post it to another topic.

```
pipeline.apply(KafkaIO.<Long, String>read()
            .withBootstrapServers(properties.getProperty("bootstrap.servers"))
            .withTopic(properties.getProperty("read.topic"))
            .withConsumerConfigUpdates(kafkaConfig)
            .withKeyDeserializer(LongDeserializer.class)
            .withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
            .withoutMetadata())
        .apply("Read message", MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
                .via((KV<Long, String> message) -> {
                    System.out.println("Message: " + message.getValue());
                    return message.getValue();
                }))
        .apply(ParDo.of(new CleanupJson(redisCache)).withSideInputs(redisCache))
        .apply(KafkaIO.<Void, String>write()
                .withBootstrapServers(properties.getProperty("bootstrap.servers"))
                .withTopic(properties.getProperty("write.topic"))
                .withProducerConfigUpdates(kafkaConfig)
                .withValueSerializer( StringSerializer.class).values());
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could help to fix this issue.

Comment: why not use Spark directly?

Comment: @AlexOtt We have few apache beam pipelines running on Google Dataflow and planning  to migrate beam pipelines into Azure platform.

Comment: Based on your description, the Apache Beam pipeline with KafkaIO doesn't work with the SparkRunner? Have you tried using DirectRunner or DataflowRunner, do they work? If it's just a runner issue, can you file a ticket to https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/BEAM/issues for this?

Comment: @大ドア東 It is working fine using direct runner in my local machine. Moreover I'm able to produce message from Spark runner using KafkaIO but It's not consuming messages.

Comment: Apache beam doesn't have streaming support on Spark Runner. They may add support in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Apache beam doesn't support KafkaIO streaming on Spark Runner. They may add support in the future.